# Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I get this error, I found many thread with the same message, but it never seems to match my case, and I didn't manager to solve it.

Basivally, everything was ok until I tried to make 1 form for create and update a 'Car' object.

Here is a presentation of my app (build from this template: https://github.com/linnovate/mean):

/public/js/config.js:

```
[...]
  .state('edit car', {
    url: '/cars/:carId/edit',
    templateUrl: 'views/cars/edit.html'
})
  .state('create car', {
    url: '/cars/create',
    templateUrl: 'views/cars/edit.html'
})
```

/public/js/services/mycars.js (don't really know what services are used for...):

```
//Cars service used for car REST endpoint
angular.module('mean.mycars').factory('Cars', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('cars/:carId', {
    carId: '@_id'
}, {
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
    }
});
}]);
```

public/js/controllers/mycars.js:

```
angular.module('mean.mycars').controller('MyCarsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Cars',
function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cars) {

    $scope.findOneOrCreate = function () {
        // create a new car
        var car = new Cars({
            id : null,
            marque: this.marque,
            modele: this.modele,
            desc: this.desc
        });

        // put new car in scope
        $scope.car = car;

        // if there is a param, search for the car (mode update)
        if ($stateParams.carId !== null){
            Cars.get({
                carId: $stateParams.carId
            }, function(carTmp) {
                       // put the result in scope
                        $scope.car = carTmp;
                    });
        }
    };

   $scope.createOrUpdate = function () {
        var car = $scope.car;

        if (car.id !== null) {
        // update
            if (!car.updated) {
                car.updated = [];
            }
            car.updated.push(new Date().getTime());

            car.$update(function () {
                $location.path('cars/' + car._id);
            });
        }
        else {
            //Create
            car.$save(function (response) {
                $location.path('cars/' + response._id);
            });
        }
    };
```

And finally my view: edit.html:

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyCarsController" data-ng-init="findOneOrCreate()">
    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-6" role="form" data-ng-submit="createOrUpdate()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="car.modele" id="title" placeholder="Title" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content" class="col-md-2 control-label">Content</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea data-ng-model="car.marque" id="content" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Content" class="form-control" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Edit to add infos:
The web Services are supposed to return only one car (but not sure if they do), here they are:

```
exports.car = function(req, res, next, id) {
Car.load(id, function(err, car) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!car) return next(new Error('Failed to load car ' + id));
    req.car = car;
    next();
});
};

exports.create = function(req, res) {
var car = new Car(req.body);
car.user = req.user;

car.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send('users/signup', {
            errors: err.errors,
            car: car
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(car);
    }
});
};

exports.update = function(req, res) {
var car = req.car;

car = _.extend(car, req.body);

car.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send('users/signup', {
            errors: err.errors,
            car: car
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(car);
    }
});
};
```

Error message appears when I go to /cars/create, not when I go to /cars/:carsId/edit:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Is your web service returning an array?  The get method expects only one object to be returned, and the same with your PUT request if you're returning something.  If you're expecting multiple you will need to specify `isArray: true` in your service method in mycars.js.  See example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I edited to show you my services, I think they return only one object (but I am not sure). Moreover: is it possible that the problem comes from the '$stateParams.carId' in my controller, because it can be 'null' when I am in create mode, and maybe that can cause errors...

Comment: You could check whether multiple objects are returned by turning on the web developer toolbar and looking at the Network tab.  It should show the response returned from your web service.  It would be helpful if you provided at least a snippet of that in your question.  Also, is there any reason you create the car object before attempting to retrieve it?  Given that your method is called "findOrCreate" it seems it would make more sense to first call the web service to retrieve it, then create the car if it is null.

Comment: I have tried with network (thanks for the tip) and it's doing a get request on my /cars service. So this is returning a list because $stateParams.carId is empty in create mode. So the problem is that this test seems to not work at all: "if ($stateParams.carId !== null)". Do you know how I can see the value of $stateParams.carId (same as debug mode in java for example)? (PS: yes I will call the find before the create, that's more logical ;) )

Comment: I find the solution, I replace the test with this: "if (typeof $stateParams.carId !== 'undefined')" and everything is working perfectly! the 'null' was wrong... don't really know why but anyway it's working.